# Increase Twilio Total Timeout from 15000ms - SMS

Tags: twilio

When an API call is made after receiving an SMS via Twilio, I occasionally get the error below -

```
Error: Total timeout is triggered. Configured tt is 15000ms and we attempted 1 time(s)
```

The API call occasionally takes longer than 15 seconds to return a response (this is due to having to process the SMS etc.). How can I configure the total timeout to say 25000ms?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to [override the timeout settings for a webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/webhooks-connection-overrides). However, the maximum total time (tt) for webhooks is 15 seconds and you cannot increase it beyond there.

If you find your service cannot respond within that time, you might want to hand off the processing of the SMS to a job and respond to the webhook quicker. If you then intend to reply to the SMS, you can do so using the [REST API message resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource) instead of TwiML.

Comment: i'm on the same boat, how do i hand off the processing to a job? i'm using python btw. I also intend to reply after the message is processed

Comment: I believe a popular Python background job library is [Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/). I’d take a look at that.

Answer (score -1):

just time it yourself and send messages using their twilio client if timed out